# Disadvantages of checking for invalid values in a textbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vbscript

I am making a userform where I want to perform a regression analysis from the input data for four functions fi(x), which are recorded in each of the corresponding textboxes.

[image: image1]

To check if the input functions are valid I have proposed two conditionals, the first one to verify that none of the textboxes are empty (this works):

```
If p = 1 Then
    box = MsgBox("No functions were provided for regression analysis.", vbInformation, "Regression Toolbox Info")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

while in the second, I want to verify that if any of the values entered is not valid, since it is not a function of x, it will inform me, e.g. if text or any other digit is entered that does not allow the calculations to be made.

```
For i = 2 To p
    If (fxn(i - 1) = "x") Then
    ElseIf IsError(Evaluate(Replace(fxn(i - 1), "x", 2))) Then
        box = MsgBox("The f" & i - 1 & "(x) input is invalid as it is not a function of x." & _
        "Check your data input and correctness of syntaxis of f(x) functions." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If you want to type in only x you should type in ""1*x""." & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Several functions with multiplication of x (e.g. fx1 = 1*x, fx2 = 2*x)" & _
        "are not allowed.", vbCritical, "Error!")
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf InStr(fxn(i - 1), "x") = 0 Then
        box = MsgBox("The f" & i - 1 & "(x) input is invalid as it is not a function of x", vbCritical, "Error!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next i
```

Regarding this last, the code that I have so far registers a failure, since in spite of entering valid functions in each one of the textboxes, it gives me the message that it is an invalid input, that is to say, it takes any value as invalid input. I have tried several modifications of the lines, but I keep getting the same error, where can I be making the mistake that does not allow me to reach the result I am looking for?

Thank you very much for your valuable cooperation.

pdt: In the following link [Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hPQXhN4nO5z_XzEeIsvTBf2kDBnmUGv5/view?usp=sharing), you can find the Workbook with the code I am working on. If the lines related to the verification are omitted, the complete code works perfectly, however, it would be missing the verification of the data entered in each of the textboxes, in order to verify if they are valid entries or not.

Comment: @Peregrino69 - Questions with regards to [VBA](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vba) and [VBScript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) can be witan scope here at Super User.  In this current form, this question appears to be within scope, since the author is asking for help with a script they already attempted to write themselfs.

Comment: Thx @Ramhound. Deleted.

Comment: When you attempt to debug the script using breakpoints. What is the returned value of `InStr(fxn(i - 1), "x")`in your conditional statement? You might also have to put breakpoints within the fxn function itself to determine the answer to the question I proposed.  If you switch to text comparison (1) `InStr([ start ], string1, string2, [ compare ])` does the behavior change?

Comment: I doubt you mean to perform a binary search instead of searching for a character in a string.  Performing a binary search would explain the reason the output is "invalid" no matter if it is valid or invalid.

Comment: Sorry for the omission of information, it usually happens to me more than usual when I propose this type of questions.

Comment: @Ramhound  What I am looking for is to check if the input functions are valid (textbox), that is to say, that they are functions that depend on the independent variable, for this case it would be "x", so that when entering in any of the textboxes, for example, a text string, or any other invalid character, it automatically marks me as error, while if I enter an input that is associated to the variable "x" (e. g: x^2, sqrt(x), 1/x, ln(x)), the code continues and performs each of the necessary calculations.

Comment: @CamilaSanchez - I am suggesting you are not using the correct syntax for `InStr` to perform a string search instead of a binary comparison in order to achieve your goals.  I will tell you what I see wrong with your current script but I won't be writing it for you.

Comment: @Ramhound dear, thanks for your help, but I am not asking for that kind of collaboration, even the InStr syntax runs without any problem, since this line only identifies if in any of the textboxes a value equal to zero (0) has been entered, which has not had any difficulty.